# Where can I learn more about Schedulers, in particular, Linux Kernel Scheduler

Tags: operating-system

As per topic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at

[Linux Kernel Documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/)

and

[Inside the Linux scheduler](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-scheduler/)

[Process Scheduling](http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html)

Comment: something more beginner-friendly?